# it is an employee data that i want to transpose row data into columns using pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, pivot-table

I have data in the following table

```
+----------------------------+
| empid empname city salary  |
+----------------------------+
| 1      a       chn 15000   |
| 2      a       chn 15000   |
| 3      b       bgl  25000  |
| 4      b       bgl  25000  |
| 5      c       hyd  30000  |
| 6      c       hyd  30000  |
+----------------------------+
```

For this above table i have to transpose the above rows into columns. I tried using pivot function but I couldn't get the correct answer. Following are the output

```
+--------------------------------------------+
| empname city Novembersalary Decembersalary |
+--------------------------------------------+
| a        chn   15000         15000         |
| b        bgl   25000         25000         |
| c        hyd    30000        30000         |
+--------------------------------------------+
```

I have tried the following query but it doesn't work well and it shows all the columns are in null state:

```sql
select empname, city, november, december
from (select empname as ename,city as loc,salary from Employees) as srctable
pivot (avg(salary) for ename in(empname,city,november,december)) as pivottabel
```

Comment: show us what you have tried as well as your desired output

Comment: *"I tried using pivot function but I couldn't get the correct answer."* And what was that attempt. It isn't in your question, so we can't tell you why it isn't working. Also `PIVOT` is an operator, not a function.

Comment: Where are you getting the dates from? The input table doesn't show dates.

Comment: Are you missing an effective date?  How do we know what is November or December?

Comment: i have tried this below query but it doesn't work well and it shows all the columns are in null state. 
select empname,city,november,december from
(select empname as ename,city as loc,salary
from Employees) as srctable
pivot
(avg(salary) 
for ename  in(empname,city,november,december)) 
as pivottabel

Comment: You need something like `avg(salary) for TheMonthName + 'Salary' in(JanuarySalary, FebruarySalary, MarchSalary, ..., DecemberSalary)`. And you can get the month name with `FORMAT(SalaryDate, 'MMMM', 'en-US')`. Therefore you must have either a date column or a column with month names in the table.

Comment: @AbdulMalik: your data has no notion of dates, so it is unclear how you define november and december in the resultset.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to everyone they are not given the correct date for the input table. Now I got the solution. Below is the solution query

```sql
select ename,loc, november, december
from (select empname as ename, city as loc,salary,datename(month,salarydate) as msalary
      from Employees) as srctable
pivot (avg(salary) for msalary in(emname,city,november,december)) as pivottabel;
```

Thank you for your valuable comment guys!!!!

Comment: The problem was that you did not mention the `salarydate` column. It is missing in your example of the first table.